# Sikuli: if else statement not working correctly

Tags: sikuli

if (Checkbox is Unchecked)
    {
      clickImage("Chechbox")

```
} 
    else 
{
 clickImage("OkButton")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?

I use Python in my Sikuli script, and I have something like:

```
if (name == 'Ente'):
     print('Name is Ente')
elif (name == 'Jamie'):
     print('Name is Jamie')
else:
     print('Name Unknown')
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code must be:

```
if (Checkbox is Unchecked):
      clickImage("Chechbox")
else:
      clickImage("OkButton")
```

Pay attention to the ":".